# Ionic display error if gps is turned off

Tags: android, cordova, gps, ionic-framework

Got a bit of an issue trying to determine if someone has their GPS turned off in Ionic/Cordova.

Here is what I am trying to do at the moment, this works in the browser fine but not on android.

```
navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(pos) {}, function(err) {
    alert('We were unable to determine your location, please turn on your GPS/Location services');
});
```

Another thing is does anyone know if its possible to give a prompt to turn on GPS with Ionic/cordova?

Anyone got any ideas?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Please add [**this**](https://github.com/dpa99c/cordova-diagnostic-plugin) plugin,

```
cordova plugin add cordova.plugins.diagnostic
```

**1.Determine if someone has their GPS turned off in Ionic/Cordova**

**`Contoller`**

```
if (window.cordova) {
    cordova.plugins.diagnostic.isLocationEnabled(function(enabled) {
        alert("Location is " + (enabled ? "enabled" : "disabled"));
    }, function(error) {
        alert("The following error occurred: " + error);
    });
}
```

**2.Giving a prompt to turn on GPS**

**`Controller`**

```
if (window.cordova) {
    cordova.plugins.diagnostic.switchToLocationSettings();
}
```

Comment: Thanks for prompt plugin, I didn't think it was existed.

Comment: Hi, I'm not the host of this topic. I answered this and saw your solution.

Comment: Is there a way to watch for location being turned on and off?

Comment: Hi, it's throwing an error 'Class not found'. any idea what's the issue?

Comment: I get the following: `[ts] Cannot find name 'cordova'.
any`

Comment: The following fixes it: `npm install -g typings
typings install dt~cordova --save --global`. but then I get the following:  `error TS2339: Property 'diagnostic' does not exist on type 'CordovaPlugins'.`

Answer (score 3):

I think it is easier when using ngCordova plugin to detect GPS status.
You can try this two plugins:

1. [$cordovaGeolocation](http://ngcordova.com/docs/plugins/geolocation/):

   - This plugin using Wifi/3G/GPS to detect current position.
   - It also has `watch` function and error callback. You should use that for checking.
2. Or [$cordovaBackgroundGeolocation](http://ngcordova.com/docs/plugins/backgroundGeolocation/):

   - This works same as `$cordovaGeolocation` but has `battery-saving` feature.
3. For prompt message, I think the only way is do it through plugin written by Java code. Check out [Introduction to custom Cordova plugin development](https://blogs.oracle.com/mobile/entry/introduction_to_custom_cordova_plugin) for more details.

Answer (score 2):

Try with this

```
let optionsGPS = {timeout: 4000, enableHighAccuracy: true};
Geolocation.getCurrentPosition(optionsGPS).then((result) => {
  this.loadMap(result.coords.latitude, result.coords.longitude);
}).catch((err) => {
  let alert = this.alertCtrl.create({
        title: 'Error on GPS',
        subTitle: 'You need active the GPS',
        buttons: ['Ok']
    });
    alert.present();
});
```

I had the same problem, and this it worked for me