# error TS2339: Property 'diagnostic' does not exist on type 'CordovaPlugins'

Tags: cordova, angular, ionic2

I am using Ionic 2.

I followed [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33373967/ionic-display-error-if-gps-is-turned-off), and did the following:

> ```
> cordova plugin add cordova.plugins.diagnostic
> npm install -g typings 
> typings install dt~cordova --save --global
> ```

**app.ts**

```
    if (window.cordova && cordova.plugins) {
      cordova.plugins.diagnostic.isLocationEnabled(function (enabled) {
        alert("Location is " + (enabled ? "enabled" : "disabled"));
      }, function (error) {
        alert("The following error occurred: " + error);
      });
    }
  }
```

I get the following error:

> `error TS2339: Property 'diagnostic' does not exist on type 'CordovaPlugins'.`

I notice that `window.cordova` is `undefined`.

If anyone can advise how I can get the Cordova Plugin working, I would appreciate it.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

So for Ionic 2, try window['plugins'] in place of cordova.plugins.